# How to combine two different size video using GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avfoundation, gpuimage

I Have on video, I am adding second video over the first video using GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter, Everthing is working fine. Now I want to know that there is any way to set two different size video and create one video.

ex. First video size is 1280*720 and second video size is 640*640 I want to set that second video over the first video using GPUImage is it possible ?

See below code which was I Implemented and it was working well with same size video but how to set two different size video please help me.

```
  fxURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"FXSample" withExtension:@"mov"];
    rawVideoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"rrecord" withExtension:@"mov"];

    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:rawVideoURL options:nil];
    AVAssetTrack *videoAssetTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];

    self.gpuMovieA = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:rawVideoURL];
    self.gpuMovieFX = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:fxURL];
    self.gpuMovieA.playAtActualSpeed = YES;
    self.filter = [[GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter alloc] init];
    [self.filter setupFilterForSize:CGSizeMake(640, 640)];
    [self.gpuMovieFX addTarget:self.filter];
    [self.gpuMovieA addTarget:self.filter];

    _gpuMovieFX.playAtActualSpeed = YES;
    self.gpuMovieA.playAtActualSpeed = YES;

    //setup writer
    NSString *pathToMovie = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/gpu_output.mov"];
    unlink([pathToMovie UTF8String]); // If a file already exists, AVAssetWriter won't let you record new frames, so delete the old movie
    NSURL *outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie];

    self.movieWriter =  [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:outputURL size:videoAssetTrack.naturalSize];

    [self.filter addTarget:self.movieWriter];

    self.movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = NO;
    self.gpuMovieA.audioEncodingTarget = nil;
    //add this line otherwise it will cause "Had to drop an audio frame" which cozes the saved video lose some sounds
    [self.gpuMovieA enableSynchronizedEncodingUsingMovieWriter:self.movieWriter];

    [self.movieWriter startRecording];
    [self.gpuMovieA startProcessing];
    [self.gpuMovieFX startProcessing];

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    [self.movieWriter setCompletionBlock:^{
        weakSelf.gpuMovieA.audioEncodingTarget = nil;
        [weakSelf.gpuMovieFX endProcessing];
        [weakSelf.gpuMovieA endProcessing];

        [weakSelf.movieWriter finishRecordingWithCompletionHandler:^{
            NSLog(@"movie writing done");
            [weakSelf.gpuMovieA cancelProcessing];
            [weakSelf.gpuMovieFX cancelProcessing];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"failed"];
                [weakSelf writeToAlbum:outputURL];
            });
        }];
    }];
```

Comment: You ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes, you need second video with green background (chrome channel) so that after overlapping it on 1st video, you have to set green color to clear color so its done, see GPUImage its possible with it.

Comment: You might find this blog post useful, it describes some of the issues and include a link to a github project that shows how to use the green screen filter with GPUImage: http://www.modejong.com/blog/post18_green_screen